# Do I have to obtain an ESTA as a VWP citizen, if I go from EU to Mexico on a direct flight?

Tags: air-travel, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, mexico

The plane won't going to land on US soil but will cross US borders on its route (in the air).

Is "Transiting" applicable only when I have a connecting flight on US ground?

What happens if we have to make an emergency landing in the US?

Comment: While you don't need a ESTA or any other paperwork with the US, it's worth knowing that the US government [will receive your information](https://www.tsa.gov/news/testimony/2014/09/18/tsa-secure-flight-program) from the airline as part of its security checks. This all happens behind the scenes and isn't something you'd be aware of or care about unless you're on some kind of US terrorist watch list, at which point you would be denied boarding. Assuming this is not the case (one hopes!), US immigration is not otherwise involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need no paperwork for any country in the world (whether the US or not) simply for flying over it. So no, you don't need an ESTA.

If an emergency landing were to occur, there are specific emergency procedures in place - for VWP nationals, this could involve obtaining an ESTA on arrival.